# Getting and setting the text of a <textarea> in typescript

Tags: html, typescript

I need get and set the text of a `<textarea>` in typescript

```
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
```

I have this code:

```
const TextArea:HTMLElement = document.getElementById('textarea');
```

This is what I tried:

```
TextArea.value = 'new value';
```

However, this didn't work. How can I set the text of my textarea?

Comment: If you want an answer in Spanish: https://es.stackoverflow.com

Comment: please help me, the question is how get and modify the text of a <textarea> in typescript

Comment: using `.value` worked in my sandbox: https://jsbin.com/juxurozasa/1/edit?html,js,output . You need to translate your question into English for this site. If you want to post your question in Spanish, use the StackOverflow en Español link I posted earlier.

Comment: i recently traduce this to english